# Will my current employer be contacted for French student visa?

Tags: visa, france, student-visa, us-citizens

I'm a United States citizen planning on taking a career break to study in France this fall, and the visa application asks for my current employer.

Does anyone know to what capacity they use the employer info? Will my current employer be contacted (they have a history of cutting people who they know are leaving). Could a trusted coworker be listed rather than HR or a manager?